# Stored Procedure fails to see parameters or returns a convert data type error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures, oledb

I've run into a rather annoying problem which I cannot seem to get to the root of.
I've searched the internet for similar problems - and I've found a few unanswered in other forums - so I thought I'd give it a go here.

The following WebMethod of a webservice contacts a database, which works fine, and runs a stored procedure.

The problem is, that when I pass the parameters as single characters it tells me it cannot find either of the parameters and when I pass a full length "ean" parameter it tells me the following error message:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Error converting data type varchar to int.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Service.GetOthersRatings(Int32 personID, String ean)
```

And now here's the Webmethod:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "GetRatings")]
public string GetRatings(int personID, string ean)
{
    string ratings = "";
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("GetRatings", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@personID",OleDbType.Integer,10).Value = personID;
    command.Parameters.Add("@ean",OleDbType.VarChar,30).Value = ean;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (myReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                ratings = myReader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ratings = "Null";
        }
    }
   catch (Exception e)
    {
        ratings = "Error - " + e.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
    }
    return ratings;
}
```

One thing that's worth mentioning is that if I remove the OUTPUT part of the SP, it runs fine down to and returns

```
    ratings = "Null";
```

But seeing that I try to read a String from the reader, I don't see why it wouldn't work with a varchar output from the SP.

In the Database we have the corresponding Stored Procedure, which works fine if just executed in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID('GetRatings') IS NOT NULL ) 
DROP PROCEDURE GetRatings
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetRatings
    @ratingschars           varchar(36) = NULL OUTPUT,
    @personID               int,
    @ean                    varchar(30)

AS
BEGIN TRAN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @pris varchar(2)
    DECLARE @forventet varchar(2)
    DECLARE @smag varchar(2)
    DECLARE @count varchar(30)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM feedback where personID = @personID AND ean = @ean)
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @pris = (SELECT CAST(pris AS varchar(2)) FROM feedback   where personID = @personID AND ean = @ean)
            SELECT @forventet = (SELECT CAST(forventet AS varchar(2)) FROM feedback where personID = @personID AND ean = @ean)
            SELECT @smag = (SELECT CAST(smag AS varchar(2)) FROM feedback where personID = @personID AND ean = @ean)
            SELECT @ratingschars = @pris + @forventet + @smag
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @pris = (SELECT CAST(avg(pris) AS varchar(2)) FROM feedback WHERE ean = @ean)
            SELECT @forventet += (SELECT CAST(avg(forventet) AS varchar(2)) FROM feedback WHERE ean = @ean)
            SELECT @smag += (SELECT CAST(avg(smag) AS varchar(2)) FROM feedback WHERE ean = @ean)
            SELECT @count += (SELECT CAST(count(*) AS varchar(30)) FROM feedback WHERE ean = @ean)
            SELECT @ratingschars = @pris + @forventet + @smag + @count
        END
    END
COMMIT TRAN
```

Which I've tried to change to output of to int, with the same error results. 
I'm stumped - I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored-procedure has three parameters where as in your code, you've added only two parameters. So add a third parameter as [OutPut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) type.

EDIT:

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SampleProc

@no1 int,
@no2 int,
@result int OUTPUT
AS
  set @result=@no1+@no2
RETURN
```

Code to execute the Stored-procedure:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SampleProc"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = cn

Dim no1 as New OleDbParameter("@no1", OleDbType.Integer)
Dim no2 as New OleDbParameter("@no2", OleDbType.Integer)
Dim resultas New OleDbParameter("@result", OleDbType.Integer)
result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

no1.Value = 10
no2.Value = 20

cmd.Parameters.Add(no1)
cmd.Parameters.Add(no2)
cmd.Parameters.Add(result)

cn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()

Dim returnResult as Integer 
returnResult=CType(result.Value,Integer)
```

Comment: That got me further, thanks
Now it keeps returning me to the Rating = "Null", but I should be able to take it from there.. Didn't think that I'd need to pass the parameter which I'm using as output.

Comment: Right, I got my SP to function as it should now - though I can't seem to get the reader to read anything. It keeps saying .hasRows is false - any idea what that might be?

Comment: @GoD1x - You can get a value from output parameter after closing the reader and connection object. Use string v=outParameter.Value;

Answer (score 1):

can you try the following?

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", personID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ean", ean);
```

Comment: can you try `@ratingschars varchar(36) OUTPUT` removing NULL? Also as @AVD suggested, can you use add a variable for output parameter? this link  might help http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/CallStoredProcedurewithinputandoutputparameters.htm

Answer (score 0):

Also, `IF EXISTS(...) ... ELSE ...` can be replaced with:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM feedback where personID = @personID AND ean = @ean)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  @ratingschars 
                = CAST(pris AS varchar(2)) 
                + CAST(forventet AS varchar(2)) 
                + CAST(smag AS varchar(2))
        FROM    feedback   
        WHERE   personID = @personID 
        AND     ean = @ean
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @ratingschars
                = CAST(avg(pris) AS varchar(2))      --or STR
                + CAST(avg(forventet) AS varchar(2)) --or STR
                + CAST(avg(smag) AS varchar(2))      --or STR
                + CAST(count(*) AS varchar(11))
        FROM    feedback 
        WHERE   ean = @ean
    END
END
```

or

```
SELECT  @ratingschars --Question: all these columns (pris, forventet, smag) are NOT NULL ?
        = CAST(pris AS varchar(2)) 
        + CAST(forventet AS varchar(2)) 
        + CAST(smag AS varchar(2))
FROM    feedback   
WHERE   personID = @personID 
AND     ean = @ean

IF @ratingschars IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @ratingschars
                = CAST(avg(pris) AS varchar(2))
                + CAST(avg(forventet) AS varchar(2))
                + CAST(avg(smag) AS varchar(2))
                + CAST(count(*) AS varchar(30))
        FROM    feedback 
        WHERE   ean = @ean
    END
```